# Filtering . (this folder) and .. (parent folder) in SFTP directory listing in C# SSH.NET

Tags: c#, .net, ssh, sftp, ssh.net

I connect to SFTP host.

That host has a folder `files`

[image]

And one file in it.

I need to get a list of names of file in that folder (files).

I tried:

```
using (var client = new SftpClient(FtpFolder, 22, FtpUsername, FtpPassword))
{
    client.Connect();
    client.ChangeDirectory("files");
    var files = client.ListDirectory(".").ToList();
    client.Disconnect();
}
```

[image]

But instead of 1 file I also get parent folder reference I think.

Please advice! Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

In SFTP protocol, there's no way to ask server to filter files for you. Nor has SSH.NET API any function to filter the files for you locally. You have to do it on your own.

For example:

```
client.ChangeDirectory("files");
var files =
    client.ListDirectory(".").
        Where(file => (file.Name != ".") && (file.Name != "..")).ToList();
```

---

Changing directory has nothing to do with the question. Actually SFTP protocol does not even have a concept of "working directory". The "working directory" is only simulated locally by SSH.NET library.

So this is functionally equivalent:

```
var files =
    client.ListDirectory("/files").
        Where(file => (file.Name != ".") && (file.Name != "..")).ToList();
```

Comment: For anyone stumbling upon this like myself, this should be the accepted answer and works.